# "Request desktop site" option on rails bootstrap website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I would like to add a "request desktop site" option on a rails website based on the twitter bootstrap framework.

Using twitter bootstrap the "desktop view" option in android browser (and probably other mobile browsers) is ignored.

I would like to give mobile users an option to fake a standard 1280x800 (or similar) resolution if the user requests it, ignoring the responsive design.

Is this implementable in a rails app?

Comment: can i ask why you want to ignore the responsive design?

Comment: @Richlewis, my project gives a slightly different experience on smaller devices since some js effects are disabled via the .hidden-phone classes. Anyway I found that some owners of high end devices prefer the full desktop experience on their phones just zooming in and out with two fingers. Facebbok for example gives this opportunity.

Comment: think this gives you your answer--- you may not like it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406610/is-there-a-way-to-give-the-user-an-option-to-view-the-desktop-version-if-they-ar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you could put all media queries in separate .less files (I think most media queries are in the files that beginning with 'responsive'). Then have two different versions of the CSS to serve up. One that everyone gets with the responsive CSS, the other that users who click the "desktop" view when they are on their mobile.